# React Native Fetch： TypeError: Network request failed

Tags: react-native, fetch

I am using React Native to make an app. Some functions in the program are called third-party services. There is an API document saying "Remove the Content-type field when sending a request"
When I delete this field in my code, Fetch cannot send the request and reports an error: TypeError: Network request failed
When I add this field, the API cannot be called
Can you tell me what to do? Is there no solution?

These are some of my codes：

Do not add a Content-type field：

```
fetch("https://xxx", {
    method: "PUT",
    body: buffer,
})
```

return:

```
Unhandled promise rejection [TypeError: Network request failed]
```

Add Content-type field：

```
fetch("https://xxx", {
    method: "PUT",
    body: buffer,
    headers: {
      "Content-Length": "application/json" //or other
    }
})
```

return:

```
Response 403
```

1. The URL is HTTPS, nothing wrong
2. I tried Postman to send the same request and removed the Content-type field and it worked
3. thanks everyone

Comment: Share the successful request from Postman.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. After I set the Content-type field to the empty string "", the program can run